# Mysql_fetch_row() проблема

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как можно исправить ошибку. Заранее спасибо!

```
*Warning:  mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in *
```

Выскакивает при добавлении в таблицу сообщения, а в дальнейшем выводе его. Вот сам код на который ссылается ошибка

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO twts(twt,time,upload_id,uid_fk) VALUES ('$twt','$time','$upload_id','$uid')";
$insert_result=mysql_query($query);

$sql="select T.tid, T.twt, T.time, T.upload_id, U.username, U.fullname, U.email FROM twts T, users U WHERE T.uid_fk=U.uid and T.uid_fk='$uid' order by T.tid DESC LIMIT 1";
$show_result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($show_result))
{
$tid= "$row[0]";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and ='$uidb' - странное условие. Тут всё правильно?

Comment: да все правильно

Comment: выведите строку реально генерируемого запроса для проверки и выполните его через PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Все равно выдает ошибку в функции

Comment: Если запрос выполняется неправильно через PHPMyAdmin, значит, он неправильно составлен. Он выполняется там или пишет ошибку?

Comment: Я немного изменил запрос в коде к ВОПРОСУ, скажите ошибка в чем все таки сейчас ?!

Comment: Если ошибка уже при первом запросе, то выведите его: echo $query; Возможно, туда поступают совсем не те значения, которые вы ожидаете. Вы увидите в браузере сам текст запроса и можете проверить, правильно ли он составлен и будет ли он выполняться в PHPMyAdmin, если нет - он вам покажет ошибку в запросе.